# Run/debug Angular 2 in NetBeans

Tags: javascript, angular, netbeans, netbeans-8

I'm starting with Angular2 and use NetBeans as my primary IDE.
I decided to use angular.io quickstart as intro to angular.
NetBeans typescript plugin is installed.

The folder is set up, node.js/npm / npm install done and everything set up.
`npm start` with lite-server works fine - project runs.

When i hit run on the project in NetBeans - it opens the index.html and i get the 
`Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined` error.

Looking at the project structure:

`quickstart\node_modules`
`quickstart\src\index.html` - made sense that it wouldn't be able to find the node_modules folder like that in `index.html`:

`<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>`

But moving the code from `src` to `quickstart` - did not help.

I cannot just open the `index.html` in a browser and run the app (considering it is javascript and should run) - and therefor i cannot use NetBeans connected  Chrome debugging.

What am i missing here?
However how do i get it to run without the live-server so i could use netbeans connected debugging?

Comment: I would rather use the Angular2 seed which uses webpack on not systemjs. https://github.com/angular/angular2-seed This project works well in Netbeans

Comment: for quickstart you should put all files in the project directory

Comment: @rjdkolb
Tried the webpack - and the same issue. Runs on lite-server, but not through netbeans.

Comment: Is this a HTML5 Netbeans project ? Are you trying to debug Typescript in Netbeans ?

Comment: Gave up with netbeans connect. Will stay with chrome debugger.